# Every Variety is Quasicompact?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

I know that this obviously isn't true, but I can't find a gap in my "proof" and it's really bothering me. Here, "variety" means reduced, separated, finite type scheme over some field $k$.

If $X$ is some variety over $k$, then the morphism $X \to \text{spec} \, k$ is finite type, thus quasicompact. Thus the preimage of open affine $\text{spec} \, k$ is quasicompact, yet this preimage is $X$, which would imply that any variety is quasicompact, which is certainly not true.

Can someone please help me figure out what is wrong with my reasoning?

Comment: Your reasoning is right.

Comment: Why do you think it obviously isn't true?

Comment: Ha, I clearly had bad intuition there, and was thinking about the classical topology and not the Zariski topology. Thanks!